# How to list files with a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, powershell

How I can do a `ls` using PowerShell?

```
for i in `ls` 
do 
    if [ -d $i ] #miro si és directori
    then
        echo "Directory"
    else echo "File"
    fi
done
```

POWERSHELL

```
$llistat -ls
forEach $element in $llistat ??? this is possible
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet works like `ls` (at least with the file system provider). All items returned have a PowerShell-specific property called `PSIsContainer`, indicating whether it's a directory or not:

```
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem)){
    if($item.PSIsContainer){
        "Directory"
    } else {
        "File"
    }
}
```

If you want to see what's inside each directory, one level down:

```
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem)){
    if($item.PSIsContainer){
        # Directory! Let's see what's inside:
        Get-ChildItem -Path $item.FullName
    }
}
```

---

As of PowerShell version 3.0 and up, the `Get-ChildItem` supports a `File` and `Directory` switch on the filesystem provider, so if you ONLY want directories, you could do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory
```

So the second example becomes:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Get-ChildItem
```

---

You could also list files recursively (like `ls -R`):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank man!!. And if I would like to print what cointains the directory $item? I should do another foreach?

Answer (score 1):

A more PoSh way is to use a pipeline, and perhaps a hashtable:

```
$type = @{
  $true  = 'Directory'
  $false = 'File'
}

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $type[$_.PSIsContainer] }
```

PowerShell even has a default [alias](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/tutorial-powershell-aliases/) `ls` for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx), so you could use more Unix-*ish* syntax:

```
ls | % { $type[$_.PSIsContainer] }
```